# How to flag a single message in a thread?

Tags: mail.app

When I select a thread and click the flag button as shown in [official guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/flag-emails-mlhlp1052/mac), it flags all the messages in the thread. This is suboptimal when the thread is long and contains many messages. How can I flag one single message in a thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the thread.
2. Scroll to the message.
3. Hover over the space above the title. The cursor should show “grab”:

   [image: grab]
4. Double click, and the message will be shown in a pop-up window.
5. In toolbar of the pop-up window, there is a “flag” button, which will only flag this message.